# Find what application is connected with what login to what database what table and what columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Is there a Script which finds the current activity 
from `application->login->Database->Table->Column`  level ?

I have used

- SP_who2, sp_who2'Active',Sysprocesses
- Activity Monitor
- Audit
- Profiler
- Trigger
- Extended Events

and coludnt get column level data connections, i was able to get the `sql` statements, table name, database,instance, application, login name ...but I couldn't get Column Names

the reason I am trying to find to track all usage and re architect the Database..

any help is appreciated

Comment: An application can only be identified by the name provided in the connection string.  In other words, you can put `App Name=XXXXX` and that is the name that will show up in all the tracking apps.  You can audit logins and cross reference them with query times gathered by profiler to find out which workstations / servers used them, and then monitor the activity on the wkstn/svr to find out what app caused it.  Going down to a table/row level will need serious auditing.

Answer (score 0):

`SP_who2` and `sp_who` are the ones I have even used to get the required information. You can as well check against `sys.sysprocesses` to know about processes that are running on an instance of SQL Server.

If you want the columns involved in the queries then consider using [`SQL Server Tracing`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191006%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) probably.